# Code Coverage Tool for Maven Project with Multiple Modules

Tags: maven, module, jenkins, code-coverage

I am working on a Maven project that consists of many modules, and we are looking into a code coverage tool. I have found a solution for simple single module projects, but I'm having a hard time finding a product or solution for code coverage with our project. Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the tool you have found doesn't work with multi model project? Anyway this question is off-topic.

Comment: I believe that Sonarqube + Jacoco would work for what I want, but I am having trouble getting them to work.